# The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using paypal adaptive payment on my project.But when i try to pay using preapproval i am getting this response from paypal

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2013-05-15T05:53:33.709-07:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Failure
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => ec16bc5b116e0
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 5867333
    [error(0).errorId] => 560022
    [error(0).domain] => PLATFORM
    [error(0).subdomain] => Application
    [error(0).severity] => Error
    [error(0).category] => Application
    [error(0).message] => The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value
    [error(0).parameter(0)] => X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID
)
```

And the transaction is failed.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The appID for sandbox and live are different. For sandbox, everyone must use `APP-80W284485P519543T`. For live, you must use the ID that matches the app's credentials.

Comment: How can we get that ID that matches our app's credentials?